# Mysql takes longer when using php or python compared to worbench queries

Tags: mysql, query-performance, php, mysql-workbench, python

Versions:
MySQL Community Server: 8.0.16 in Windows server (Configuration file: unknow)

Workbench: 8.0

Problem:

When I make a query through workbench, it takes 1 second but when I make a query through PHP or Python, it lasts 30 seconds and the state in which it appears in the Worbench connections is: "sending data". The engine tables I consult is MyISAM.

The response of query is too short this is the problem.

#### Update

I tried to use MariaDB with same tables and the response time between the workbench and the programming languages are almost similar...

Comment: I find it strange that PHP and Python have the same delay time. I measure the response time according to how long it takes to bring the data. I have tried with different tables and queries and minimizing the code to a single script that only connects to the database and makes the query and I always received similar response times, faster in the workbench than with the languages

Answer (score 0):

UIs (such as Workbench) silent tack on a `LIMIT` to constrain the amount of output.  This speeds up *certain queries*.  I suspect this explains the alleged difference.

Running the 'same' (or, in some cases, 'similar') twice in a row -- the second one *may* be much faster than the first.  This is due to "caching".  Run your queries both ways again.

I suggest you look at `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; you may find that the table is not really `ENGINE=MyISAM`.  8.0 is seriously deprecating that old Engine.  I recommend you take the hint and move to InnoDB.

"long it takes to bring the data" -- That sounds like it includes the web page rendering.  Instead, add code to actually capture the time before and after.

Comment: Rik! Thanks for your answer, but: The queries that I have tried are of few rows, I also tried to use InnoDB but it was slower, the tests I did with the script were only for consultation without anything extra

Comment: @Ignakal - Even 1 second is much too long for "a few rows".  So, I have to believe that something else is involved.  I would expect something like 20 _milliseconds_, even on a cold system with a slow disk and a web page to out the few rows on.